# Activate a modal by clicking on a geometry

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, openlayers

I have to display a Bootstrap's modal when clicking on a geometry.
With the following code I am able to take the pk of the geometry, check that it is present in the dictionary and then get the modal id:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  attributeTable = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });

  const storyPointDict = [
  {% for storypoint in single_object.stop_point.all %}
      {
        id: {{ storypoint.id }},
        modal_name: 'storyPoint{{ storypoint.id }}'
      },
      {% if forloop.last %}{
        id: {{ storypoint.id }},
        modal_name: 'storyPoint{{ storypoint.id }}'
      }{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  ];

  if (attributeTable) {
    const fid = attributeTable.get('pk');

    for (var key in storyPointDict) {
      if (fid == storyPointDict[key].id) {
        let value = storyPointDict[key].modal_name;

        $(value).modal('show');
      }
    }
  }

});
```

So with `$(value).modal('show');` I believed that it was possible to show the modal with a specific id, but it isn't.

How can I achieve this?

I'm using Django, I'm be able to show a list of buttons that correctly activate a modal.

```
{% for storypoint in single_object.stop_point.all %}
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#storyPoint{{ storypoint.id }}">
...
        </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="storyPoint{{ storypoint.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="storyPoint{{ storypoint.id }}Title" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
...

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to show an existing modal that run if I click on a button but it doesn't run if I click on a geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself. The problem was the hashtag.

```
$('#'+value).modal('show');
```